# Regarding 8085 DAD timing diagram

Tags: 8085

Can anybody tell me about DAD instruction in 8085. Is ALE high twice in 
first machine cycle of  DAD instruction. Can anybody suggested me timing 
diagram of DAD and HLT instruction.(Any other link)

Comment: What exactly are you doing that makes these questions important? Partial answer: There's no reason to think that ALE would go high more than once during any machine (memory) cycle.